# Why RML Report is bigger when i generate it on Ubuntu vs MacOS

Tags: odoo, openerp-7, rml

I work developing modules with Odoo. I have been presenting some issues when I try to generate an RML report. My development environment is set up on a Mac but my company's Odoo production server is on Ubuntu. When I print the report on my mac, the size is 7kb but when I do it on the Productions server is 47kb. Any thoughts?

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow!
Please check [FAQs on **Asking**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking)
and make it  [Minimal, Complete and Verfiable Example(**MCVE**)](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Is the report generated by `wkhtmltopdf`? I know from experience that the output from Odoo is wildly different on Mac (poor output formatting) vs Ubuntu (good output formatting) at least in newer versions of Odoo.

Comment: Well, I do not see difference (Quality terms) but in Mac is 40kb lower in size, and that is really good for me because one of the departments prints over 700 objects at the same time, and those less kb represent a huge difference in performance. In your experience do you know if there is something I can try in Ubuntu to optimize the size those reports??